# In "Call of Duty: Ghosts", is Riley mind-controlled or given orders?

Tags: call-of-duty

In *Call of Duty: Ghosts*, there is a dog named Riley. How does the dog respond to commands?  Is he mind-controlled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [*Call of Duty* Wikia](https://callofduty.fandom.com/wiki/Riley_%28Ghosts%29), Riley has a **shortwave radio** mounted to his flak jacket as well as an [earpiece](https://www.psu.com/a021136/Why-CoD--Ghosts-Riley-is-set-to-become-gamings-most-realistic-dog?page=3) that allows him to hear your orders.

During stealth and POV sequences, you're viewing through his **mounted camera** and using a **vibrating collar** to direct his actions (which is probably what's giving you the impression that mind-control is involved)

[image: Riley's Suit]

[image: Riley Report]